# Change event data Object in Object (Array in Array) JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

i have this problem. I have array like this:

```
const a = [{name: 'A'
           car:[{color: 'red',type: 'limbo'},
                {color: 'blue',type: 'yamaha'},
               ]
           }, 
           {name: 'B'
            car:[{color: 'green',type: 'beam'},
                ]
           }
          ].
```

Nơw I have to create 2 funtion for 2 button:

- The first when click, add 1 more the car of name === 'A' with {color: 'black',type: 'mitsu'}
- The second when click, change the car with type === beam of name === 'B' with {color: 'black',type: 'mitsu'}

I'm just new in this type, so can anyone help me? I have try 2 map(), or map() inside find(), but still not work @@. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
const a = [{name: 'A'
           car:[{color: 'red',type: 'limbo'},
                {color: 'blue',type: 'yamaha'},
               ]
           }, 
           {name: 'B'
            car:[{color: 'green',type: 'beam'},
                ]
           }
          ].
function addCar(name, car) {
  return a.map(it => {
    let res = it
    if(it.name === name) {
      res.car.push(car)
    }
    return res
  })
}

function changeCar(name, car) {
  return a.map((it, i) => {
    let res = it
    if(it.name === name) {
      let carIdx = res.car.findIndex(it=> it.type === car.type)
      if(carIdx >= 0) {
        a[i].car.splice(carIdx, 1)
      }
    }
    return res
  })}
```

try this